# How to set align for cells in GridView?

Tags: android

I have the following layout:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridViewCalendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="7" >
</GridView>
```

And the following code makes simple ArrayAdapter:

```
private View initializeCalendarScreen(LayoutInflater inflater) {
    View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, null);
    GridView events=(GridView)layout.findViewById(R.id.gridViewCalendar);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    events.setAdapter(adapter);
    return layout;
}
```

It works, but text in cells isn't on the center - it has got default align by left. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create your own layout for the items instead of using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
the layout is made this way as seen on the android SKD:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

You can simply copy that but put android:gravity="center" or modify it to suit your needs